# Are there rules which tell me what form of STDOUT/STDERR/SDTIN I have to choose?

Tags: perl, stdout, stdin, stderr

Sometime I have to use the bareword "STDOUT", sometimes the bareword doesn't work and sometimes I can use the bareword or another form. Are there rules, which tell me when I have to choose on form and when another and when I can choose the form?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.12.0;
use utf8;


print STDOUT "Something\n";             # works

print \*STDOUT "Something\n";           # String found where operator expected 

print { STDOUT } "Something\n";         # Bareword "STDOUT" not allowed while "strict subs" in use 

print { \*STDOUT } "Something\n"        # works


my $fh;

$fh = -t STDOUT ? STDOUT : STDERR;      # Bareword "STDOUT"/"STDERR" not allowed while "strict subs" in use

$fh = -t STDOUT ? \*STDOUT : \*STDERR;  # works

$fh = -t \*STDOUT ? \*STDOUT : \*STDERR; # works
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are the rules according to my tests:

1. when `use strict subs` is in effect, the bareword versions can't be passed as filehandles, presumably because they could be subroutine calls.
2. The `*STDOUT` and `\*STDOUT` versions can be used to pass to functions all the time.
3. passing one of them to a sub with `foo STDOUT` (without parentheses) breaks because perl assumes that is `STDOUT->foo`.
4. Aside from cases 1 and 3, you can pass them to subs with the bareword verisons as well.
5. for calls to `print`, `printf` etc, you must either use the bareword versions, or use `{}`.  enclosing the filehandle in `{}` tells perl that yes the first argument is a filehandle, so you can use any form.

For these purposes `-t` counts as a sub, as do other `-X` tests that accept filehandles.

When you use `{}` with `print` or `printf`, the part inside `{}` is a code block; it is evaluated and the result is used as the filehandle.  It works with those functions because they are treated specially by perl, in the same way as `map` and `grep`.

So follow these rules and you will be okay:

- when printing to STDERR or STDOUT explcitly, use the bareword version:

  ```
  print STDERR "ERRORRRRR\n";
  ```
- when using a filehandle in any other way, use the `*` version:

  ```
  my $isterm = -t *STDOUT;
  close(*STDERR);
  ```

I tested as far back as perl 5.8.7.  This is as far back as I can go right now.  The above *should* work for 5.6 as well.

Comment: And how about `print { \*STDOUT } "Something\n";` (the author states it works) and your 5th rule ?

Comment: perldoc.perl.org says *FILEHANDLE may be a scalar variable containing the name of or a reference to the filehandle, thus introducing one level of indirection.* for `print`. At the end the *block* case is also described.